# Quelle phrase ci-après est correcte?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, pronoms-relatifs, formulation

1. C’est bien le gars à qui je pensais qui est mort d’un accident de la route hier.
2. C’est bien le gars que je pensais qui est mort d’un accident de la route hier.

Au sens de: C’est bien le gars que j’avais en tête qui est mort d’un accident de la route hier.

Si d’autres tournures vous viennent à l’esprit, n’hésitez pas à me les faire connaître!

Comment: la première phrase est très naturelle, rien à redire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None a donné la bonne réponse (+1).

On constate cependant dans certains cas un certain relâchement en français parlé et il n'est pas rare par exemple d'entendre « C'est pas **celui que** je pensais. » (au lieu de ***celui à qui*** ou ***à lui que***) sans que ça choque l'oreille outre-mesure.

On peut aussi considérer la phrase avec ***que*** comme ayant une une partie sous-entendue :

> C’est bien le gars que je pensais (être mort) qui est mort d’un accident de la route hier [...]

Answer (score 3):

Dans l'emploi donné ici le verbe *penser* est intransitif (penser **à**<sup>1</sup>) le mot qui précède « je pensais » est un pronom relatif complément d'objet indirect de *penser*.  Donc des deux phases proposées la seule qui soit correcte est :

> C'est bien le gars à qui je pensais...

« Que» ne serait possible qu'avec un verbe appelant un complément d'objet direct, par exemple :

> C'est bien le gars que j'aimais qui est ...

Mais on pourrait aussi dire :

> C'est bien le gars **auquel** je pensais qui est...

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Je pense au (contraction de *à le*) gars qui...</sup> 
<sup><sup>2</sup> À noter que sur certains forums on trouve que  *auquel* – contraction de « à lequel » –   (et ses déclinaisons *auxquels, à laquelle, auxquelles*) ne s'emploie que pour les choses ou les animaux, ceci n'a à mon avis aucun fondement, ni Grevisse ni les grammaires que j'ai pu consulter à ce sujet n'en parlent.</sup>